# Runtime error in codenameone aap

Tags: runtime, runtime-error, codenameone

when I run the app on my Samsung Galaxy S duos (didn't test on other devices), it's giving me error/exception

java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError:org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher

but its running fine on emulator.

I have added bouncy castle jar in my libraries.

Comment: You mean `BouncyCastleCN1Lib.cn1lib` and not `BouncyCastleCN1Lib.jar`? Did you do `refresh libs` after adding it?

Comment: The file name was something different and not BouncyCastleCN1Lib and it was jar file , i had downloaded it from BouncyCastleCN1Lib website and i refreshed libs after adding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the BouncyCastle.jar you downloaded from their website and click this [link](https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bouncy-castle-codenameone-lib/raw/master/BouncyCastleCN1Lib.cn1lib) to download the CN1Lib version supported by Codename one.

Place the file in the **lib** folder of your project and do `refresh libs` on your project.

Comment: The file is not a jar file so I did zip and added it to libraries, now its showing me error: package org.bouncycastle.crypto does not exist
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;

Comment: Click the link in the answer to download the right file and replace any files you added from their website with it.

Comment: The link which you provided downloads BouncyCastleCN1Lib.cn1lib and when i zip it and add it to libraries it gives me error

Comment: You don't have to zip it, download it as it is and place it in your Lib folder, then right-click on your project in ide and do refresh libs

Comment: What you said i tried doing that but there is no paste option when i click on libraries

Comment: What IDE are you using, Netbeans IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Netbeans  ide

Comment: Open your Netbeans project folder in **Document** look for your app folder and open it, you will find lib folder in there. paste the file inside this folder. Go back to Netbeans, right-click -> Select CodenameOne -> Refresh Libs and that's all you need to do.

Comment: I am not able to built the apk now my app size is 1164kb which is more than the prescribes 1024kb. any idea how to decrease the jar size ? I tried  to unzip the jar but all are useful  components in it .

Comment: Trying to force your project to stay below 1024kb will not be possible at some point, I will suggest your sign up as a basic or pro user which allow unlimited builds. You can start with a 2 weeks no obligation trial and enjoy all the goodies that comes with pro subscription...during this period you can test your current app thoroughly without restriction.